# How come I'm using a non-existent table in my database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having some problems with my model, so I logged in to the server to check out the mongdb instance thats running there... but it states my table does not exist??

Mongo console:

```
> use testdb
switched to db testdb
> show collections
system.indexes
```

And my application:

Connection:

```
module.exports = {
    'database': 'mongodb://username:password@host:27017/testdb'
};
```

Model:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', new Schema({ 
    username: String, 
}));
```

Adding user:

```
var nick = new User({
    username: "Nick",
}).save(function (err, userObject) {

    if (err) {
        return res.json({ "success": false, "error2 ": err });
    } else {
        res.json({ "success": true, "msg": "user created" });
    }
});
```

Listing users:

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {

    User.find(function(err, users) {
        res.json(users);
    });
});
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "56577d259bef807424cd98eb",
    "__v": 0
  },
  ...
]
```

So something is written to the database, and something is read... but there is no table. Sorry, I'm new to MongoDB, so could anyone explain this? I've checked the admin and the local db but no User table there either.

Comment: None of your code above actually inserts anything into a collection, therefore there's nothing to return when you you "find" it.  `mongoose.model` only tells your js application the schema of the data.  If you hop in the MongoDB console and do some inserts to get some data in there and then run this, you'll get results.  You could also generate some inserts from mongoose, or by doing a mongoimport of some data from the cli.

Comment: Furthermore, you can happily insert data into a non-existing MongoDB collection with our creating it explicitly. MongoDB will take care of creating the collection and an index on `_id`.

Comment: @doicomehereoften1 I added the part where I add a user (dummy). I've been using it all along.

Comment: So you still haven't given us a fully reproducible example. That being said, what you have provided leads me to believe that you're still not actually inserting anything. Check the Mongoose documentation for `exec`. When you assign a mongoose "query-ish" type of operation to a variable it is not executed immediately, allowing you to build it up bigger in subsequent steps in your JS. `nick` is one such instance of this. Running `nick.exec();` should actually trigger the `save()` to run.